# Is there any way to send data to cumulocity without physical devices

Tags: cumulocity, webmethods

**Finding a way to push data to cumulocity without physical devices**

I am trying to find a way to push data to cumulocity without physical devices. is there any to implement in java?

If there is a way, please drop some snippets and doc links.

Comment: If you insist on coding in Java, the answer below might help. Else, no coding necessary at https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/cumulocity

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example implementation in Java for an MQTT client here: https://cumulocity.com/guides/device-sdk/mqtt-examples/#hello-mqtt-java.

Examples in other languages are next to it.

You can also use a tool like MQTTBox or MQTTFx if you don't want to implement something.